# Determine whether a time series is ergodic

Tags: time-series, econometrics, convergence, ergodic

How to determine if this time series is ergodic? According to the ergodic theorem the mean must converge to the expected value starting point. How do I determine that? Hoverever I have plotted the mean observations for the last 500 days, and it seems that it doesn't converge so I can conclude it is not ergodic?
[image]

Comment: are you looking for a hypothesis test, or just an intuitive description for what ergodicity means?